# Redirect back to previous page with data after search laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i have this search functionanlity in one of my page that when the user clicked search it would go to a controller where it would search a table according to the users input then i would revert it back to the previous page but the records that should be displayed is already based from the search. what i have done so far is the search function and it is already working here it is

```
public function tsearch()
{
    $rnme = Input::get('rname');
    $ath  = Input::get('auth');
    $fsze = Input::get('fsize');
    $ftyp = Input::get('ftype');
    $dc = Input::get('dcreate');
    $du = Input::get('dupload');
    $wld = Input::get('wldcrd');

    $sbar = Input::get('searchb');
    // dd($sbar);

    // dd($sbar , $rnme , $ath , $fsze , $ftyp , $dc , $du, $wld);
    $subcatid = Session::get('SCid');

    $NSAdata = DB::table('nsa_fileuploads AS fu')
            ->join('nsa_systemusers AS nsu' , 'fu.sid' , '=' , 'nsu.sid')
            ->join('nsa_subcategory AS sc' , 'fu.subcategoryid' , '=' , 'sc.subcategoryid')
            ->join('nsa_maincategory AS mc' , 'sc.maincategoryid' , '=' , 'mc.maincategoryid')
            ->select('fu.fileid' , 'fu.filename' , 'fu.filesize' , 'fu.filetype',
                     'fu.thumbnail' , 'fu.confidential' , 'fu.sid', 'nsu.username',
                     'sc.subcategoryname', 'fu.updated_at' , 'fu.created_at', 'mc.maincategoryname' , 'sc.subcategoryid' )
            ->where('fu.subcategoryid' , '=' , $subcatid);

    $tick = "";

    if($rnme == 'true')
    {
        $tick = $tick . " rname";
        $NSAdata = $NSAdata->where('fu.filename' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sbar.'%');
    }
    if($ath == 'true')
    {
        $tick = $tick . " auth";
        $NSAdata = $NSAdata->where('nsu.username' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sbar.'%');
    }
    if($fsze == 'true')
    {
        $tick = $tick . " fsze";
        $NSAdata = $NSAdata->where('fu.filesize' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sbar.'%');
    }
    if($ftyp == 'true')
    {
        $tick = $tick . " ftyp";
        $NSAdata = $NSAdata->where('fu.filetype' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sbar.'%');
    }
    if($dc == 'true')
    {
        $tick = $tick . " dc";
        $NSAdata = $NSAdata->where('fu.created_at' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sbar.'%');
    }
    if($du == 'true')
    {
        $tick = $tick . " du";
        $NSAdata = $NSAdata->where('fu.updated_at' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sbar.'%');
    }
    if($wld == 'true')
    {
        $tick = $tick . " wld";
        $NSAdata = $NSAdata->where('fu.wildcard' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$sbar.'%');
    }

    $NSAdata = $NSAdata->get();

    dd($NSAdata);

    Redirect::back()->with('NSAdata' , $NSAdata);
}
```

my problem now is how to redirect it back to the previous page with the data i have searched so far i'am using this

```
Redirect::back()->with('NSAdata' , $NSAdata);
```

but it just redirects to a blank white page. any ideas on how i can do this? thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is after all a response which you are not *returning* here. To fix that part, simply prepend the missing return statement.

```
return Redirect::back()->with('NSAdata' , $NSAdata);
```

Also, remove the `dd` function since it dumps the variable and then ends further execution of the script. You can use the `dump` function instead.